# Price sorting and price filter are not working in Products which has custom options Magento

Tags: magento2, bug

Sort by Price and price filter showing wrong products in the result only for those products which have custom option.

Comment: Are you verified in default magento?

Comment: I have verified only sorting issue in default Magento and it was there.

Comment: Do you mean default magento also having issue ?

Answer (score 1):

If your Magento 2 store is displaying the wrong products when sorting by price or using the price filter and the issue seems to only affect products with custom options, it could be caused by a conflict with the way Magento is indexing those products.

**Here are a few troubleshooting steps you can take to resolve the issue:**

Check the product settings: Make sure that the products with custom options have been properly configured with the correct price and attribute values. It's also important to make sure that the products are set to be visible and in stock.

**Reindex the product data:** Go to `System > Index Management` in your Magento admin panel and click on `"Reindex Data"` for the "Product Prices" and "Catalog Search" indexes. This will ensure that the product data is up to date and indexed properly.

**Check the product price index table:** In your database, check the `"catalog_product_index_price"` table to ensure that the prices for the products with custom options are being calculated correctly. If the prices are not being calculated properly, you may need to troubleshoot further to determine the root cause.

**Check for conflicts with other extensions:** If you have any other third-party extensions installed, they may be conflicting with the way Magento is indexing the product data. Try disabling any extensions that relate to product indexing, sorting, or filtering to see if that resolves the issue.

**Check for custom code conflicts:** If you have any custom code that relates to product indexing, sorting, or filtering, it may be conflicting with the default Magento behavior. Try disabling any custom code related to these features to see if that resolves the issue.

If the above steps do not resolve the issue, you may need to engage a Magento developer to help you troubleshoot further and resolve the issue.